Как ставить знаки, если прямая речь находится внутри авторских слов, и почему их надо ставить именно так?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Как ставить знаки? По правилам, конечно! А еще правила можно обобщить, чтобы понять принцип решения и лучше запомнить. Но почему знаки надо ставить именно так? И можно ли их проверить интонацией?
Такие вопросы кажутся лишними, но вот не всегда. И правила можно неправильно понять или не понять вовсе.
По теме на форуме Смешение знаков при прямой речи

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Розенталь § 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора
ПАС под ред. Лопатина § 136
ПРЯМАЯ РЕЧЬ ВНУТРИ СЛОВ АВТОРА, СХЕМА А—П—А
Тема 1. Постановка запятой: схема А: «П», а.
Тема 2. Универсальные схемы с тире
Тема 3. Две реплики разных лиц

Примечание. Материал полностью соответствует правилам Розенталя и ПАС, но при решении использовано авторское обобщение темы.
ТЕМА 1. ПОСТАНОВКА ЗАПЯТОЙ: схема А: «П», а.
ОБЩИЙ ПРИНЦИП РЕШЕНИЯ
Если на месте разрыва слов автора находится ЗАПЯТАЯ (на различных основаниях), а прямая речь является ПОВЕСТВОВАТЕЛЬНОЙ, то прямая речь естественным образом встраивается в общую структуру предложения, и тогда после неё сохраняется запятая.
В этом случае увеличенная предупредительная пауза перед прямой речью отсутствует,  а на месте двоеточия делается  небольшая произносительная пауза.
(1) ЗАПЯТАЯ МЕЖДУ ОДНОРОДНЫМИ СКАЗУЕМЫМИ (повествовательная прямая речь)
Отец Василий сказал: «Да, вот так», вздохнул, помолчал и ушёл.

(2) ЗАПЯТАЯ В СЛОЖНОСОЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ (повествовательная прямая речь)
Брат вдруг говорил: «Мишка, пойдём на биллиард», и они по три часа играли 
на биллиарде. 
Ему сказали: «Ответа не будет», и он ушёл.
Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно», но глаза его 
блестят, полные зависти.

(3) ЗАПЯТАЯ В СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ (повествовательная прямая речь)
Когда вы мне ответили: «Этого не может быть», значило ли это никогда?
Он рассеянно говорил: «Да, хороша», когда ему говорили, что Элен 
красавица.
По правилам дуэли, прежде чем провозгласить роковое: «Раз, два, три», 
секундант обращается к противникам с предложением о перемирии.
Она сказала: «Гроза-то не унимается», когда молния в очередной раз 
осветила крыльцо и часть сада.

(4) ЗАПЯТАЯ ПОСЛЕ ОБОСОБЛЕННОГО ОБОРОТА (повествовательная прямая речь)
Пробормотав: «Барчуки проклятые», он закурил сигару и плотнее завернулся в 
шинель.
Хозяева, говорившие всем: «Очень рады вас видеть», так же встретили 
Ростовых.
Подумав: «Ну, всё кончено, слава богу, завтра увижу Серёжу и Алексея 
Александровича», Анна вошла в спальный вагон и села на диванчик.
Софья Карловна ещё раз поцеловала Маню и, сказав ей: «Поди, гуляй, моя 
крошка», сама поплелась за свои ширмы .

(5) ЗАПЯТАЯ ПЕРЕД ДЕЕПРИЧАСТНЫМ ОБОРОТОМ (повествовательная прямая речь)
Лермонтов писал: «Так жизнь скучна, когда боренья нет», говоря о высоком 
предназначении человека.

ТЕМА 2. УНИВЕРСАЛЬНЫЕ СХЕМЫ С ТИРЕ:
(1) А: «П» — а. (2) А: «П?» — а. (3) А: «П!» — а. (4) А: «П…» — а.
ОБЩИЙ ПРИНЦИП РЕШЕНИЯ:
Если прямую речь не удается встроить в предложение, то после нее ставится универсальное тире, а в устной речи на месте тире делается пауза.  Это возможно в двух случаях: (1)  На месте прямой речи не было знаков; (2) прямая речь не является повествовательной. Такая пауза позволяет выразить вопросительную или восклицательную интонацию в устной  речи.
Таким образом, при наличии собственных знаков в прямой речи (вопросительный или восклицательный знак, многоточие) тире нужно в любом случае.
НЕТ ЗНАКОВ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ НА МЕСТЕ РАЗРЫВА СЛОВ АВТОРА (ставится тире при любой интонации для прямой речи)
(1) НЕТ ЗНАКОВ (в исходном предложении)
Со словами: «Прощайте и будьте здоровы» — он вышел из комнаты. 

На мой вопрос: «Жив ли старый смотритель?» — никто не мог мне дать ответа.
Из дрожек выскочил человек и с криком: «Евгений Васильевич!» — бросился к 
Базарову.

(2) СОЮЗ «И» МЕЖДУ ОДНОРОДНЫМИ СКАЗУЕМЫМИ (нет знаков в исходном предложении)
 Он сказал: «Вы мне ничуть не мешаете» – и продолжал выбирать из фуражки 
спелые черешни».
Она сказала: «Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками» 
— и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку. 
Денисов сказал: «Ну, прощайте, графиня» — и, не взглянув на Наташу, вышел.

Часовой сурово окликнул: «Кто там?» — и вскинул ружьё.     
Николай думал: «Неужели французы?» — и смотрел на них, не веря глазам.
Градоначальник произнёс: «Не потерплю!» — и скрылся в комнате.
Он сказал: «Извините...» – и закрыл дверь.
Тут уж он и совсем обомлел: «Ваше благородие, батюшка барин, да как вы… да 
стою ли я…» — и заплакал вдруг.

НА МЕСТЕ РАЗРЫВА СЛОВ АВТОРА СТОИТ ЗАПЯТАЯ, НО ПРЯМАЯ РЕЧЬ НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ПОВЕСТВОВАТЕЛЬНОЙ (ставится тире)
Это тот случай, когда запятая "поглощается" тире.
(1) ОДНОРОДНЫЕ ЧЛЕНЫ, СОЮЗЫ А, НО
И не грозился снег: «Вот стаю!» – а под ногами всё крепчал.
Мама всегда говорит: «Прекрасно!» – а потом пишет на другой стороне 
рисунка свои статьи.

(2) ОБОСОБЛЕННЫЙ ОБОРОТ
Думая: «Я сам во всём виноват, что надеялся. Кто я и что я?» – Левин 
пешком направлялся к брату.
Ещё раз повторив «Через час!» – он направился было к дверям.

(3) СЛОЖНОСОЧИНЕННОЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ
Псари кричат: «Ахти, ребята, вор!» – и вмиг ворота на запор.
Она ожидала, что Иван Иванович воскликнет: «Не может быть!» – но он 
промолчал.

(4) СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННОЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ
 Когда пешеход спросил у Эзопа: «Сколько часов ходьбы до Афин?» – мудрец 
 не сразу смог ему ответить.

ТЕМА 3. ДВЕ РЕПЛИКИ РАЗНЫХ ЛИЦ ВНУТРИ  СЛОВ АВТОРА
В этом случае ставится единый знак запятая и тире:
Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», — «Да, 
недурно», — отвечал он обыкновенно. (Г.); 
Когда приходил к нему мужик и, почесавши рукою затылок, говорил: «Барин, 
позволь отлучиться на работу, подать заработать», — «Ступай», — говорил он 
(Г.) 


"Это тот случай, когда запятая "поглощает" тире".   Наверно, нужно написать "запятую" или "поглощается".

Спасибо!  Я как раз именно это имела в виду)

Некоторые впечатления от темы
Из вопроса:
  Однако это правило как-то однобоко 
  воспроизведено. Так, непонятно, снимают ли 
  дополнительный знак — запятую (даже если он 
  требуется по условиям контекста) многоточие, 
  вопросительный знак и восклицательный.

  Нельзя говорить, что запятую "снимают".

ВВОДНАЯ ЧАСТЬ
Почему одно и то же правило одним кажется простым, а другим, напротив, непонятным? Действительно, всё же просто, вот ведь:
Посмотрите еще раз (§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора):

пункт первый — ставится только запятая;
пункт второй — ставится только тире;
пункт третий — запятая и тире (для двух реплик).

Ну что здесь непонятного, читают невнимательно? Другой вариант — слишком внимательно? Не знаю, что и думать.
А думаю, что все мы разные. У одних хорошая зрительная память — им такое правило выучить как нечего делать.  Часто с этим связана так называемая орфографическая грамотность. И вот чем больше человек склонен к размышлениям, тем хуже запоминает правила без объяснений, а также правильное написание слов.
Другими словами, чем больше думаешь, тем хуже запоминаешь и тем больше склонен к недоверию: правило? а почему такое правило? а что оно означает?
О СМЕШЕНИИ ЗНАКОВ
Так было ли там "смешение", отменяется запятая или нет? Поглощает тире запятую или оба знака присутствуют? Вот что сложно в этом правиле, если есть желание его понять, а не просто запомнить.
Дело в том, что тема единого знака (ЗАПЯТАЯ И ТИРЕ)  здесь посторонняя, в действительности она из другой темы (две реплики!) и стоит особняком.
У Розенталя об этом говорится в самом конце, в этом еще разобраться нужно. А вот у Лопатина тема двух реплик вообще в другом параграфе. Но в ответе по теме об этом не сказано, что меня удивило.
§ 137. Если прямая речь принадлежит разным лицам, то каждая реплика выделяется кавычками ОТДЕЛЬНО:
г) запятая и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими 
разным лицам, но объединенными общим авторским предложением: 
Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то 
сделать»,  — «Да, недурно», — отвечал он обыкновенно (Г.); 

ВЫВОД
Не такая это простая тема, что все дело в невнимательности тех, кто ее не понял. В действительности здесь два решения а не три. А две реплики — это уже о другом.
И тире здесь действительно поглощает запятую (отменяет ее).
